# User authentication and password storage in R Shiny using sodium

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, passwords, libsodium

I am implementing a log in page to a ShinyApp (I cannot use any paid features of Shiny Server Pro or anything like that) and came accross some sample code to do so on the following website:
https://www.listendata.com/2019/06/how-to-add-login-page-in-shiny-r.html

It uses the sodium package which is build on sodium to store and check passwords. The relevant code is

```
credentials = data.frame(
  username_id = c("myuser", "myuser1"),
  passod   = sapply(c("mypass", "mypass1"), sodium::password_store),
  permission  = c("basic", "advanced"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
)
```

The use inputs a username and password through a text box and then the shinyapp checks for a match using the function `sodium::password_verify`

The first thing I noticed is that the passwords get stored as rownames:

```
> credentials
        username_id
mypass       myuser
mypass1     myuser1
                                                                                                       passod
mypass  $7$C6..../....etc..
mypass1 $7$C6..../....etc..
        permission
mypass       basic
mypass1   advanced
```

Is this a mistake? Surely this defeats the point of storing the passwords as hashes.

Once I've added `row.names = NULL` to the dataframe, is this a reasonably secure method to store log in details? Are there other methods/packages or other free services to manage user accounts and authentication to Shiny?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a mistake

Comment: To the second question: I would say no, this is not a reasonably secure method. For two reasons: without examining it in detail, it looks like a DIY solution, and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own ; second, security is partly a matter of trust, and the mistake you've pointed out does not inspire trust.

Comment: To the third question, even though recommendations are typically considered off topic on StackOverflow, I would point to https://github.com/datastorm-open/shinymanager or https://github.com/Tychobra/polished , look up their authors, Github issues (open and closed), to make your own idea. A more complex and integrated product that handles authentication, and is free, is ShinyProxy.